# Adding a class to a .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, colorbox

new to StackOverflow and relatively new to JavaScript/jQuery. I've been trying to develop a website that contains a vector map (using the Raphael plugin), and when a particular area of the map is clicked, I want it to open a Lightbox using the Colorbox plugin. I have the Raphael and Colorbox plugins working individually (I've got the hover function working for Raphael, and I've got the Colorbox to work when a normal  link is clicked). However, I'm not sure how to get the Colorbox to work when it is a Raphael element that is clicked.

This is because I think I need to add the "inline" class to the Raphael element, however my .click function can only get a url (I can't add a class).

Apologies if this question doesn't make much sense, I've been going round in circles for hours now.

Current .click function. locs is an array of the Raphael objects in a separate document. locarr is an array containing these objects for a for-loop. id and url are elements of the Raphael object.

```
    .click(function(){
       location.href = locs[locarr[this.id]].url
    })
```

The Colorbox works with a normal link, like below. But I can't figure out a way to add the class to my .click function. I've tried various versions of .addClass and similar with no success.

```
<a href="#link" class="inline">LINK</a>
```

I think my problem is because the Raphael objects do not exist in the HTML (the url is taken straight from the JavaScript document.

Sorry again if this doesn't make sense. Thanks.

Comment: damn that's a confusing question ...

Comment: maybe add this to a jsfiddle ?

Comment: what do you mean: "add the class to my .click function"

Comment: @Gung Foo sorry, that should say "add the class using my .click function"

Comment: You said in a comment below that _"the link isn't really a link (it isn't in my HTML document anywhere, it exists solely in JS)"._ A link can't exist in JS - do you mean the link element is added to the page via JS? If so you can still attach event handlers to it or otherwise manipulate it from JS.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I mean (the link comes from a for-loop in my JS).

Answer (score 0):

Not going to pretend to try and understand full well what you want, so I am going off the current title. If thats the case and you want to add a class to an element for styling purposes of one sort or another and you want it to do this when the link is clicked on you can try..

```
$('.inline').click(function(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault();//stops the mouse click from triggering a normal click event
    $(this).addClass('className');//adds a defined class from your stylesheet
    //$(this).css({"color":"#FF0"});//changes the style properties without a class
  });
```

Since your saying in the comments your JS is generating the link. You can try..

```
$('body').delegate('click', '.inline', function(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault();//stops the mouse click from triggering a normal click event
    $(this).addClass('className');//adds a defined class from your stylesheet
    //$(this).css({"color":"#FF0"});//changes the style properties without a class
  });
```

or you can try

```
$('.inline').live('click', function(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault();//stops the mouse click from triggering a normal click event
    $(this).addClass('className');//adds a defined class from your stylesheet
    //$(this).css({"color":"#FF0"});//changes the style properties without a class
  });
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for: the link isn't really a link (it isn't in my HTML document anywhere, it exists solely in JS). I'm not 100% sure how it works, but I think the class is a JS class, not a CSS class (it isn't in my CSS file, it's only in the jQuery file for the Colorbox). I'm confusing myself; I think I might just need to find a different way to do this.

Comment: in the context your talking about, it is the equivelent of a css class, selector wise, just cause the JS generates the the link (which I didn't know) doesnt mean that its JS specific. Anyway, with that said, elements generated by javascript are not part of the DOM at the time of rendering, they are added in there after via javascript. with that, you need to use something like `.live()`, `.delegate()` or something or another to cycle over the elements in the DOM including new ones generated by JS

Comment: delegate when you can use it, is the better choice as its better at preventing memory leaks that can occur on occasion with not so well thought out code.